# Asymptotic convergence of sampling distribution of the sample variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution, chi-squared

Let's consider a set $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^N$ of $N$ i.i.d. random variables drawn from the distribution $P_X(x) = \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Define the variable
$$\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{N} \sum_i (X_i - \hat{\mu})^2$$
where $\hat{\mu} \equiv \frac{1}{N}\sum_i X_i$; it follows that (see for example [here](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/lesson/26/26.3)) :

$$\hat{\sigma}^2 \sim \frac{1}{2^{\frac{N-1}{2}}\Gamma\left( \frac{N-1}{2}\right)}x^{\frac{N-3}{2}} \left( \frac{N}{\sigma^2} \right)^{\frac{N-1}{2}} e^{-\frac{x}{2} \frac{N}{\sigma^2}} \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (1)$$

Now, given that $\hat{\sigma}^2$ is the sample variance, from the law of large numbers, in the $\lim_{N \to \infty}$, $\hat\sigma^2$  [converges in probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_probability) to the expected value $\sigma^2$.

**Question:**

Is it possible to show that in the $\lim_{N \to \infty}$ the measure of $\hat\sigma^2$ distribution (Eq. (1)) concentrates around the value $\sigma^2$, *i.e.*
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} P(|\hat \sigma^2 - \sigma^2|>\epsilon )=0 \;,  \;\;\; \forall \epsilon>0 \; \;?$$

Comment: $(N-1)\hat{\sigma^2}/\sigma^2 \sim \chi^2(n-1) = \text{Gamma}\left(\frac{N-1}{2},\frac12\right)$. It is know that for large $N$, the distribution $\text{Gamma}\left(\frac{N-1}{2},\frac12\right)$ is approximately $\mathcal{N}\bigl(N-1, 2(N-1)\bigr)$. So $\hat{\sigma^2} \approx \mathcal{N}\bigl(\sigma^2, 2/(N-1)\bigr)$ which goes to $\sigma^2$. This is not formal, of course.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @StéphaneLaurent . Is it possible to formally show the convergence in probability you mentioned directly starting from the form of Eq. (1)

Comment: you want to proof $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(  | \hat{\sigma}^2  - \sigma^2 | \geq \epsilon) = 0$ ?

Comment: user1172131> If you just want the convergence in probability of $\widehat{\sigma^2}$ to $\sigma^2$, you don't need the normality assumption on the $X_i$: this convergence always holds true when the $X_i$ are iid with a finite variance, and this is a classical application of the weak law of large numbers. So you don't need the distribution of the estimator.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thanks fo your comment; I know the resuts can be proved from LLN (even in more broad settings). My question for the specific case presented is if the result could be also shown directly applying the limit to the distribution (as we have the form of it for generic $N$). After your comment I modified the quetion to be more clear

Comment: user1172131> What do mean by "concentrate around", precisely?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I edit the question to be more explicit as it could have caused confusion; is it more clear now?

Comment: user> Sorry but I don't understand what you want. $\lim_{N \to \infty} P(|\hat \sigma^2 - \sigma^2|>\epsilon )=0$ is the convergence in probability, and as we already said it follows from the WLLN, without the need of the explicit distribution.

Comment: I would like to show the convergence without emplying LLN but starting simply from the limit of r.h.s. of Eq.(1) for N going to $\infty$

Comment: user> Maybe (I didn't try) you can approximate $\Gamma\left(\frac{N-1}{2}\right)$ with the Stirling formula to show that this density of $\widehat{\sigma^2}$ converges pointwise to $0$ everywhere except at $\sigma^2$ as $N\to\infty$. But assuming this is true, I don't see how one could deduce the convergence of probability from this pointwise convergence.

Answer (score 2):

Your assertion

> we expect that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \hat{\sigma}^2 = \sigma^2$

needs some clarifying. Because $\hat{\sigma}^2 $ is not a deterministic function of $N$, it's a random variable. Then we need to specify in what type of [convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables) we are speaking of.

Typically, in this case (an estimator), we want convergence in probability, ([consistent estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_estimator)). For which a sufficient (non necessary) condition is convergence in mean square, which in turn is verified if the estimator ins unbiased (or at least asymptotically unbiased) and its variance tends to zero.

Comment: thanks for the comment @leonbloy ; I corrected the question specifying the convergence in probability. If there are other points not clear please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\hat{\sigma}^2 &= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N (X_i -\hat\mu)^2\\
&=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N (X_i^2 -2\hat\mu X_i +\hat\mu^2)\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i^2\right)-\hat\mu^2\\
\end{align}$$

As $(X_i)_i$ are i.i.d, according to the [**strong** law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law):

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i^2\xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{\text{a.s}} \mathbb{E}(X_i^2) = \sigma^2+\mu^2\tag{1}$$
and
$$\hat\mu= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i\xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{\text{a.s}} \mathbb{E}(X_i)=\mu \implies \hat\mu^2 \xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{\text{a.s}} \mu^2 \tag{2}$$

From $(1)(2)$, we deduce the convergence almost surely of $\hat{\sigma}^2$:
$$\hat{\sigma}^2\xrightarrow[n\to+\infty]{\text{a.s}} \sigma^2 $$
And it's known that the [Convergence almost surely implies convergence in probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_almost_surely_implies_convergence_in_probability).